# How to create grid style QListWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyside

I'm currently working on a list which I'd like to have set up in a grid style and was curious how I could go about that. I don't believe a table will work because I'd like to have it formatted like this:

```
option  option  option  option

option  option  option  option

option  option  option  option

option  option  option  option
```

~4 options per row and no further information split into columns where each row represents a single ListWidgetItem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for something like this (explanation is inline):

```
QListWidget *listWidget = new QListWidget;

//Dynamically adjust contents to viewport size.
listWidget->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);

//Forces the layout into a grid (64x64 is an arbitrary value).
listWidget->setGridSize(QSize(64, 64));

//As an alternative to using setGridSize(), set a fixed spacing between items in the layout:
listWidget->setSpacing(someInt);

//This sets the Flow to LeftToRight, which is more natural in a grid.
listWidget->setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);
```

Play with these properties in Qt Designer. Start by setting [`QListView::Flow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistview.html#ViewMode-enum) and going from there until you get the behavior you desire.

Comment: Thanks, yours was the only answer which fulfills my needs. I'll give it a shot when I get into work tomorrow!

Comment: Whoops. I realized you want to max at four columns. You may need to do some more tweaking to get that behavior, since `QListWidget` fills all available space.

Comment: No worries, it was pretty easy once I got this info. For anyone curious you just set wrapping to true then you do something like list_width = items_per_row * list_item_width

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if you have a static number of items, you can use a QGridLayout.

If you have a QAbstractListModel, you can implement your own view, by implementing QAbstractItemView and QAbstractItemDelegate, which is what QTableView does.

Comment: It will be a varying number of items which are added on the fly. Also, is there any examples on how to do that as I'm not familiar on how I would change the layout using the QAbstractView (I'm using pyside so most everything I do is through qt designer)?

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88: I never touched pyside or qt designer, so I can't help you there. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [`QTableWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html) or [`QTreeWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html).  When the items in a row are closely related to a single item (ie. each row is an item, and each column is an attribute of that item), I've found using a `QTreeWidget` is easier.

```
tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
tree.setHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Age', 'Weight'])
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['John Doe', '24', '150'])
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['Jane Doe', '21', '120'])
```